# Android MediaMetadataRetriever extracting genre bad format

Tags: android, metadata, mp3

i'm having a problem with MediaMetadataRetriever when extracting GENRE meta data from a mp3 file.

```
    MediaMetadataRetriever metadata = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    String path = file.getPath();
    metadata.setDataSource(path);
    String album = metadata.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
    Log.v("METADATA->", "Album: " + album);
    String artist = metadata.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    Log.v("METADATA->", "Artist: " + artist);
    String genre = metadata.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
    Log.v("METADATA->", "Genre: " + genre);
```

Everything is working OK but GENRE isn't...

In a mp3 file where GENRE is 'Rap' i get from log:

```
V/METADATA->: Genre: (15)
```

In a mp3 file where GENRE is 'Hip-Hop' i get from log:

```
V/METADATA->: Genre: (7)
```

Solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, searching for a while in Google i went to this web and realized why my genre was a "number". Genre metadata is stored in one unique byte and i found a list os genres ordered by it's byte value:
[ID3v1 genre list](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Appendix_A_-_Genre_List_from_ID3v1).

Comment: You did not say in your original Question that you were working with ID3 version 1. Anyways at least it's solved

Comment: It's the first time i work with mp3 tags and i did not know what was ID3. I set the tags using Windows, i guess it's using ID3v1... If I use MP3Tag instead of Windows, genre is stored as a character string. And yes, it's solved.